# Variable power with negative irrational exponent, wrong result but why?

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, irrational-numbers

*I'm sorry for my english math terms, I'm trying to translate them from Italian, hopefully everything is correct.*

On my textbook I have this exercise (Powers with irrational exponents chapter):

$(a^2-1)^{-\sqrt{2}}$

And I'm asked to say for what values of $a$ this power is meaningful so this is what I did:

*I know that $a^2 -1$* must be greater than $0$ because the exponent $-\sqrt{2}$ is a negative irrational number

$a^2-1>0$

$a^2>1$

$a>\pm\sqrt1$

$a>\pm1$

Now I know this is wrong but I really have no idea how to get to the correct result which is:

$a<-1\lor a>1$

I've searched on the book, online but never received any satfisying answer.

Comment: If you draw a graph of $y=x^2 - 1$ it should be "obvious" that $a^2 - 1 > 0$ when $a < -1$ or $a > 1$. To prove mathematically that this is the correct answer is just a little bit more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be very careful when taking square roots because $\sqrt{a^2}$ really means $|a|$. Your confusion arises when you claim that $a > \pm \sqrt{1}$ because, while this is true for equalities, it isn't necessarily true for inequalities.

In this case you have two cases; either $a$ is positive or $a$ is negative. If $a$ is positive then we can conclude that $a > 1$. However, if $a$ is negative then we have to be careful about our signs: $-a > 1 \implies a < -1$.

A safer way would be to factor the original expression as a difference of squares:

\begin{align}
a^2 - 1 &> 0 \\ (a-1)(a+1) &> 0,
\end{align}

and then you have $3$ regions to check.

Answer (score 0):

After $a^2 > 1$ you can conclude with $a<-1 \lor a>1$. [Think about which numbers $a$, after squaring, become $>1$.] Be sure you understand why going to $a>\pm \sqrt{1}$ is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why it's wrong actually. EDIT: Also the correct result makes sense but is there a procedure to follow to get there?